# Jekyll Styles not rendering either on localhost:4000 or my Github, anyone to advise?

Tags: styles, localhost, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm using trying Jekyll Bootstrap for my blog. I've been coding with Ruby and RoR for a while. I managed to host my app on Github Pages (https://mukunzichild.github.io). However as you can see, CSS styles (Bootstrap 3) are not rendering.

I've searched on google but came up with nothing. Some people have had problems with Jekyl styles with version 3, but it was not like mine.

I even cloned the Jekyll bootstrap repo, and it only fires HTML when I run it locally. I haven't changed anything in the default files.

Let me know if there is anything I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's A Jekyll Bootstrap problem ([see issue here](https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/issues/320)).

You can resolve this by changing bugged code in your **_includes/JB/setup** by former code :

```
{% capture jbcache %}
  <!--
  - Dynamically set liquid variables for working with URLs/paths
  -->
  {% include JB/is_production %}
  {% if site.JB.setup.provider == "custom" %}
    {% include custom/setup %}
  {% else %}
    {% if is_production and site.JB.BASE_PATH and site.JB.BASE_PATH != '' %}
      {% assign BASE_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
      {% assign HOME_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign BASE_PATH = nil %}
      {% assign HOME_PATH = "/" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
      {% assign ASSET_PATH = site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
    {% else %}
      {% capture ASSET_PATH %}{{ BASE_PATH }}/assets/themes/{{ page.theme.name }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}{% assign jbcache = nil %}
```